# Excel; How to get month info from week number? Year starts from February

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In excel, I have fiscal year and fiscal week data as follows.

```
FiscalYear FiscalWeek Month
2014       1          
2014       1
.          .
.          .
```

I want to convert fiscalweek data to fiscal month. In this case, fiscal year starts February 1st. So 
[Desired output data]

```
FiscalYear FiscalWeek Month
2014       1          2
2014       1          2
.          .
.          .
```

Using

```
=MONTH(DATE(A2,1,B2*7-2)-WEEKDAY(DATE(B2,1,3)))
```

for Month column, I get 12, or December instead of February.

How can I get the appropriate month info from the FiscalWeek info?
Thanks!

Comment: In 2017, Feb. 1 falls on a Wednesday............what do you consider the first day of the first fiscal week in 2017 ??

Comment: (1) Are you running a fiscal year of February to January regardless of day of the week? (2) Do you just want a list as shown in your question or is this an investigation leading to a UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table below, I

1. Filled column A with repeats of 2014
2. Filled column B with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …
3. Set cell C2 to =MONTH(DATE(A2,2,1+(B2-1)*7))
4. Formatted cell C2 as Number with zero decimal places
5. Copied cell C2 down.

This is setting the day value in the formula to 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36, 43, …

The specification of function DATE says:

> If ***day*** is greater than the number of days in the month
>   specified, ***day*** adds that number of days to the first day in the
>   month. For example, DATE(2008,1,35) returns the serial number
>   representing February 4, 2008.

[image: Desired result]